# Okhttp ignores Dispatcher setting when used with Retrofit RxJavaCallAdapterFactory

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

Consider the following initializations of OkHttp and Retrofit:

```
public static SomeServiceRestInterface newRestService(String apiUrl) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(apiUrl)
                    .client(createOkHttpClient())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                    .addConverterFactory(createGsonConverter())
                    .build();
            return retrofit.create(SomeServiceRestInterface.class);
}

private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
                    Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
                    dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(1);
                    dispatcher.setMaxRequests(1);
                    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                .dispatcher(dispatcher).build()
}
```

When testing the rest calls, I've noticed that Okhttp doesn't honor the setMaxRequestsPerHost or setMaxRequests settings at all. Here is the log of 3 requests dispatched simultaneously:

```
23/07 04:14:22.668 [RxIoScheduler-4] DEBUG - --> POST https://XXX/1 http/1.1
23/07 04:14:22.668 [RxIoScheduler-4] DEBUG - Content-Length: 0
23/07 04:14:22.668 [RxIoScheduler-4] DEBUG - --> END POST (0-byte body)
23/07 04:14:22.672 [RxIoScheduler-7] DEBUG - --> POST https://XXX/2 http/1.1
23/07 04:14:22.673 [RxIoScheduler-7] DEBUG - Content-Length: 0
23/07 04:14:22.673 [RxIoScheduler-7] DEBUG - --> END POST (0-byte body)
23/07 04:14:22.676 [RxIoScheduler-6] DEBUG - --> POST https://XXX/3 http/1.1
23/07 04:14:22.677 [RxIoScheduler-6] DEBUG - Content-Length: 0
23/07 04:14:22.677 [RxIoScheduler-6] DEBUG - --> END POST (0-byte body)
```

where XXX is the same domain, 1/2/3 are different paths.

I'm not sure why but I thought this possibly has to do with the RxJava Scheduler set in addCallAdapterFactory.

Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

I'm using okhttp 3.4.1, and retrofit 2.1.0.

Comment: Have you checked how many http clients you create?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote Jake Wharton on this issue:

> The implementation of Observable for Retrofit executes requests
>   synchronously relying on the applied Scheduler for any necessarily
>   limiting. If you need the limits from OkHttp's Dispatcher to be
>   honored, then you'll have to write a custom CallAdapter for Observable
>   which uses Call.enqueue instead of Call.execute.
>
> We currently have no plans to support this, although it's likely that
>   Retrofit v3 built on a hypothetical OkHttp v4 might make this the
>   default (though this is a long way off).
>
> This is the same behavior you would see if you used Retrofit's Call
>   and called .execute(), or even used OkHttp's Call with its .execute().

Answer (score 2):

As of retrofit 2.9, the method `createAsync()` of both `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` and `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` creates CallAdapter that uses `Call.enqueue`. This delegates the queuing to OkHTTP's `Dispatcher` so the maxRequest settings work.

`create()` and `createWithScheduler()` will skip the `Dispatcher` by using `Call.execute`.

For `RxJava3CallAdapterFactory`, the names were swapped: `create()` is now the async adapter, while the previous direct-execute version was renamed to `createSynchronous()`