# Retrofit one api call at a time

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I have a server that support 1 api call at a time, i have tried adding `Dispatcher` to my retrofit Okhttp client like this:

```
           Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
            dispatcher.setMaxRequests(1);

            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .dispatcher(dispatcher);
```

but that did not worked as expected ,

> Dispatcher enqueue api calls connections and does not wait for
>   response but i want to wait for one api call response and then start
>   a next one

In the meantime during one api call next one if requested should wait before the first api call give reponses.

What can be done in this case, Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why not build a "Pre Request" Throttler class which adds calls to a queue and only executes a new call when an old call has finished?

Comment: That is also the way but do i really have to built that , isn't there anything we do with already provided functionality in okhttp or retrofit ?

Comment: correct me if i misunderstand this, but why not just flatmap your requests ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody because there are multiple request in multiple screens i cannot combine all api calls in faltmap , because there is no order

Comment: oh ok i get what you're saying now

Comment: According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542465/okhttp-ignores-dispatcher-setting-when-used-with-retrofit-rxjavacalladapterfacto) SO and [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1936) discussion, I guess there is no way you can do it with Retrofit or OkHttp. You might be able to use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())` on all network calls instead.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can send requests via `execute` method of Retrofit. See [this](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute--)

Comment: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory call `execute` on backend instead of .enqueue that is why this issue is happening so this answer won't solve my question